# Creating random float and float64 arrays in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, random

I would like to create two random arrays in NumPy for a fixed, given shape. 
`np.random.randn(A,B,C)` creates a random array of float64, if i am not mistaken, how do i create one filled with `float32`?

If i am mistaken, then my question still pertains, just the other way around.

Comment: `mat = np.random.randn(1, 3, 4).astype(np.float32)` for example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert your array after initialization as follow :

```py
mat = np.random.randn(A,B,C)
mat = mat.astype(np.float32)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass **dtype** as follows:

```
np.array(np.random.randn(1,2,3), dtype=np.float32)
```